# Instagram Oauth - allow user's to choose which account to login with?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, oauth, instagram

I've integrated my React app with Instagram Basic Display. My user's are successfully able to link their Instagram account to my app.

However for user's that have multiple Instagram accounts, I've noticed that the Authorization Window displayed when going through Instagram's Oauth flow does not contain the ability to switch accounts.

Is their some way to enable user's going through the Instagram Oauth flow to switch between accounts and select which account they would like to link with my app?

Comment: We've ran into the same issue. The auth flow isn't great on Instagram.

Comment: Yeah copy that. I've scoured the docs and internet and the only solution I've seen is calling the instagram "logout" endpoint before asking the user to connect their instagram. Doing so will ensure the Oauth interface for instagram as a "Switch Accounts" button. It seems hacky but it feels like further support for any instagram api not on the facebook graph is very limited. For reference I embed the logout endpoint in an 0 pixel image source like so. ```<img src="http://instagram.com/accounts/logout/" width="0" height="0" />```

Comment: I've seen that as well. So calling that URL has worked for you? Do you add that img before you redirect to the Ouauth endpoint?

Comment: @jontetz Yeah I load a "Connect Instagram" page with this hidden image and a button. When the user clicks the button it sends them to the OAuth endpoint. In theory you'd want to make sure the image loaded before the button was clicked, but I don't bother and haven't run into any issues.

Comment: Yep, that does appear to be working!

Answer (score 0):

If you add `force_authentication=1` to the login oAauth URL, it will force the user to enter their credentials.

`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?force_authentication=1&client_id=${IG_APP_ID}&redirect_uri=${IG_REG_REDIRECT_URL}&scope=${IG_REG_SCOPE}&state=1&response_type=code`

I take no credit for this answer, I found it in another questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787472